# Sql Server Express 2012 says "Property MasterDPath is not available"

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

Sql Server 2012 Express says that "Property MasterDBPath is not available...".

I guess this is why I can't restore backups among other problems.

The message is:

[image]

This is the first time I get this message, and I have installed the software in several of my machines successfully.

What could I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install SQL Server 2012 SP1 and see if that fixes it.  See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/726826/management-studio-exception-for-localdb-instance